# Selecting any branch from Azure Repositories for a particular release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to setup a Azure DevOps release pipeline such that the branch (which will be the sole artifact for the release) can be specified when I manually trigger the release.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the branch for the repo if you manually trigger the release, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful? Is your issue solved?

Comment: Thanks Cece for your response. And sorry for delay from my end.

Comment: Thanks Cece for your response. Your solution requires me to change the definition of the release pipeline by `edit`ing the artifact. When I am doing the release, I need to open the artifact and change the branch to my private branch and save the pipeline. Only after saving, I will be able to click `create release`. After doing `create release` the artifact's definition will not go back to the original default branch that I initially set.
Your solution works but is there another cleaner way without modifying Artifact definition and saving it?

Comment: You could simply create a new release pipeline, or you can add a command line task to run git command to check out the repo and branch you want. The recommended way is using YAML build instead of classic build, YAML build is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you need to create pipeline with Azure Repos artifact like here

[image]

But you don't want to releases created automatically, right? So you just need to not enable `Continuous deployment trigger`

[image]